# Is it possible to ping between two VLANS same on the same box in the same network?

Tags: linux-networking, vlan

Note; [Originally posted in Network engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56887/is-it-possible-to-ping-between-two-vlans-same-on-the-same-box-in-the-same-networ?noredirect=1#comment98755_56887) 
I have a box running Ubuntu and connected to another box running software which simply changes VLAN and ifc.

```
Ubuntu   -- (vlan 100 on ifc1 say eth1)-------       Box
         -- (vlan 200 on ifc2 say eth2)-------

 2 VLAN say 100 and 200 (vlan100, vlan200 in interface ifc1 and ifc2). 



Note:

vlan100 is configured with IP 192.168.1.1 
vlan200 is configured with IP 192.168.1.2
```

Another side I have a device connected on which simply changes swap VLAN in the packet from 100 to 200 and vice versa on packets received on ifc1 and ifc2. Also, the device sent packets received on ifc1 to ifc2 and vice versa.

I see when I ping ARP request goes out from ifc1 and received on ifc2 and vlan200 interface gets ARP request but this interface is not responding for the arp response.

My question is: Is it possible to ping between two VLANS same on the same box in the same network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically no. Vlan is a technology to isolate networks on layer 2. Ip adresses are layer 3, means that they are not condidered when dealing with layer2 separation. ARP is broadcasted at mac address level, which means any network card on the network sould recieve it. For further details see:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol

Answer (score 2):

No as it's the same network. In general you should avoid having two VLAN but in the same address space. Generaly speaking that will add a administration burden and block intervlan routing.

The logic is your default gateway, a router possibly, will check the subnet mask, and will decide where to send the packet, but when your computer on VLAN100 try a ping, it will detect the IP on the same subnet as is, as it's the same range, and will try a broadcast discover on the switch to know who is 192.168.1.2 (ARP), the packet will never go to the router.

> In general, you should avoid having two hosts with the same IP
>   Address. There are two options for supporting this configuration with
>   guest LAN or VSWITCH:
>
> IP layer networks The OSA-Express IP Layer implementation isolates
>   specific network frames by VLAN tag, but does not isolate IP Address
>   registration by VLAN group. Therefore, you must create two guest LAN
>   segments, or two VSWITCH segments using two different OSA cards, to
>   allow two different hosts to register the same IP Address. Two guest
>   LAN segments would automatically be isolated (unless a virtual router
>   is deployed) and two VSWITCH segments would be isolated if the
>   external switch hardware configures a unique VID set for each physical
>   OSA connection.
>
> Link layer networks (layer2) The OSA-Express Layer 2 implementation
>   allows the hosts to manage IP addresses and ARP cache, so it is
>   possible to have a single guest LAN segment (or VSWITCH segment) where
>   two different hosts use the same IP Address on different VLAN groups.
>   The network must be defined with the ETHERNET option (instead of the
>   default IP Layer options), and the virtual hosts must be configured to
>   use layer2 (instead of the default). The ARP traffic for a given VLAN
>   group will only be visible to authorized members of that VLAN group.
>   Note, however, that in order to support this configuration, neither
>   host can be a member of the VLAN group assigned to the other.
>   Furthermore, all switches and routers in the broadcast domain must be
>   configured to avoid forwarding network frames from one VLAN to the
>   other.